# I want to ask about two recursive sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

```
f(0) = 1
g(0) = 1
f(x+1) = ((f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2)
g(x+1) = f(x)g(x)
```

Is it possible to find a closed form for these two functions?

Comment: Written in this way it's not really two recursive sequences, but a recursive pair of sequences.

Answer (score 6):

$f(n)$ is sequence [A073833](https://oeis.org/A073833) and $g(n)$ is sequence [A073834](https://oeis.org/A073834) in the OEIS,
you can find all information there.

Comment: Just in case the two links become dead in the future: $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are the numerator and denominator respectively of the sequence $b(n) = b(n-1) + \frac{1}{b(n-1)}$ for $n > 1$ and $b(1) = 1$.

Comment: @mhdadk I'd never imagine I'd say this, but as of 2023, the likelihood of those links becoming dead are less than this site becoming dead itself. Even after https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5737/70594 ...